# subprocess.check_output() module object has out attribute 'check_output'

Tags: python, hadoop

I am playing with the subprocess library. I can perform

`v = subprocess.check_output("ls")`

and it works fine. However, when I SSH into a machine and I want to perform a hadoop command,

`v = subprocess.check_output("hadoop fs -ls /path/to/file* | grep -oE '/(.*)'")`

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

Not quite sure why. I think it might be my lack of understanding of subprocess. How can i fix this error?

Comment: what version of python on the remote machine?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 2.6.7

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`check_output` was introduced in `python 2.7` so won't work for `< 2.7`.

You can use `Popen` with `communicate` to get the output.

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
proc = Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=PIPE)
print(proc.communicate()[0].split())
```

[This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) part of the docs may be useful

Comment: Would you happen to know an alternative? I simply want to get the output into a list

Comment: I will add something in a couple of minutes

Comment: I read around about Popen and that deadlocks occur? This is something I am worried about. How could I prevent this from occuring?

Comment: do you mean using  multiple processes?

Comment: @Liondancer If you look at the sources of [`check_output`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ffbbd43d7342/Lib/subprocess.py#l565) you'll see that *it does exactly what described in the answer*. It has a bunch of other code to set up the arguments and handle exceptions, but what it does is simply create a `Popen` and call `communicate`.  The note you are referring to is only valid when the subprocess produces *a lot* of data. In such cases you have to read "lazily" from the process `stdout` to avoid the buffering.

Comment: @Bakuriu My subprocess does produce a lot of data which is why I am concerned.

Comment: @Liondancer As far as I can see from the docs you have 2 choices: 1) Use `communicate` to avoid deadlocks, but this is buffered and thus you cannot handle *very big* outputs or 2) use the [`stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) attribute to read the data directly, which would allow unlimited output size (given you read it fast enough to avoid filling the buffer) but may cause deadlocks (however I believe the chances of causing deadlocks are very small).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think you might be missing a word haha not quite sure what you mean in your question

Comment: @Liondancer,lol,  yes missing part of it, I was basically asking what Bakuriu has already commented on. If you wanted to read from stdout instead

Comment: @Bakuriu the commands I want to run produce a huge list of file paths. I want to run these commands a few times. It seems like #2 is a better choice but the deadlocks can potentially cause my big headaches and something I would like avoid

Comment: @PadraicCunningham maybe I should just write the output to a file so I wouldnt have to deal with these issues. Could these be an alternative with no consequences besides and extra file?

Comment: @Liondancer, don't see any issue just redirect  stdout

Comment: To get the output as one string just remove split()

Answer (score 3):

Here is my version of **subprocess.check_output** function for Python 2.6 and it supports pipe lines along with habitual command interface.

```
import subprocess

def check_output(cmd):
    """ https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen
        Implementation subprocess.check_output() for Python 2.6
     """
    process_list = []
    cmd_list = cmd.strip().split("|")
    for i, sub_cmd in enumerate(cmd_list):
        STDIN = None
        if i > 0:
            STDIN = process_list[i - 1].stdout
        process_list.append(subprocess.Popen(sub_cmd, stdin=STDIN, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True))
    if len(process_list) == 0:
        return ''
    output = process_list[i].communicate()[0]
    return output
```

Test call:

```
print check_output('ls -la /var | grep log')
```

Output:

> drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Dec 11 13:22 log

Comment: Added "shell=True" and removed unnecessary lines. That will fix running "curl" commands.

Answer (score 2):

padraic-cunningham, while your answer got me part of the way there, in my case the command is an SSH command.  Since communicate kills my process prematurely(as soon as it reads an EOF character), I've found the following works better:

```
import subprocess

def check_output(command_list):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.wait()
    return proc.stdout.read()
```