# Python subprocess has no attribute "check_output"

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have code that uses `subprocess.check_output` just fine, I had to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 and afterwards it's complaining that it now can't find the attribute check_output.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.check_output("here is a command", shell=True)

/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/username/subprocess.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/subprocess.py", line 1, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/home/username/subprocess.py", line 4, in <module>
    p = subprocess.check_output("here is a command", shell=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

Note that I am using Python2.7 which according to this post here should resolve this problem but it doesn't.

[subprocess.check_output() module object has out attribute 'check_output'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894024/subprocess-check-output-module-object-has-out-attribute-check-output)

What gives? I tried pip install `subprocess` or pip uninstall `subprocess` but no luck. How do I update `subprocess` to the latest version so that it has the `check_output` attribute? I don't want to use `Popen`.

Comment: Can you show us how you know for sure that you're using Python2.7? Can you provide some output from running the same steps in the interactive shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you have created a script, called `subprocess.py`, so the original library `subprocess` was "overridden" by your module.

Rename your script */home/username/subprocess.py* to something that is not the name of the standard Python module! This rule of course applies to all the other Python libraries!

Comment: Wow you're right, I just overlooked the fact that I named the file subprocess.py . What a lame problem :(

Comment: just another example of how python needs to fix package vs. relative imports.